# Adding category title to wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin to add a list of categories and 4 posts to the home page of a website.

What I am trying to do is add the title and a "More" link to each category but I can't quite get it right.

Below is the plugin code, with my new section highlighted in comments near the bottom. At the minute, it is only showing the title for the first 2 categories, then repeating the same titles and their links again, even though the category is different.

```
<?php
    global $post;

    // default attributes for shortcode
    $shortcode_default_attrs = array(
         'author' => '',
         'show' => 5,
         'excerpt' => 'false',
         'thumbnail' => 'false',
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'category' => '',
         'tag' => ''
    );

    // overrides default attributes set above and separates into individual varaibles.
    if(!empty($inserted_attrs)) {
        extract(shortcode_atts( $shortcode_default_attrs, $inserted_attrs ));
    }

    if(!empty($author)) {

        // checks if there are multiple authors set.
        $author_has_comma = strpos($author, ',');
        if($author_has_comma === false) {

            // gets the author data for a single author.
            $author_data = get_user_by( 'login', $author );

            if(!empty( $author_data)) {
                $post_args = array(
                    'author' => $author_data->ID,
                    'posts_per_page' => $show,
                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                    'category_name' => $category,
                    'tag' => $tag,
                );
            }

        } else {

            // gets the author data for multiple authors.
            $authors = explode(',', $author);
            $author_data = '';
            foreach($authors as $author_login) {
                $author_user = get_user_by('login', $author_login);
                $author_data .= $author_user->ID . ',';
            }

            $post_args = array(
                'author' => $author_data,
                'posts_per_page' => $show,
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'category_name' => $category,
                'tag' => $tag,
            );
        }
    } elseif (empty($author)) {

        $post_args = array(
            'author' => $author,
            'posts_per_page' => $show,
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'category_name' => $category,
            'tag' => $tag,
        );
    }

    // gets posts form database
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

    // displays posts 
    if($post_query) {
        $data = '';
        $data .= '<div class="recent_post_by_cc"><ul>';
        while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
            $data .= '<li>';



            // displays a link to the post, using the post title
            $data .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">';
            $data .= get_the_title();
            $data .= '</a>';

            // display a linked featured image if post has
            if($thumbnail == 'true') { 
                $data .= '<div class="cc_left">';
                if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
                    $data .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">';
                    $data .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'thumbnail');
                    $data .= '</a>';
                }
                $data .= '</div>';
            }



            // displays the post excerpt if "excerpt" has been set to true
            if($excerpt == 'true') {
                $data .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
            }

            $data .= '<div style="clear: both;"></div></li>';
        endwhile;

        // =================================================
        // Start of my added section
        // =================================================

            $data .= '<div class="more-home-link">';
        $category = get_the_category(); 
        $data .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">More</a>';

        $data .= '</div>';


            $data .= '<div class="home-title">';
            $categories = get_the_category();
         echo '<h2><a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'</a></h2>' ;
        $data .= '</div>';

        // =================================================
        // End of my added section
        // =================================================

        $data .='</div>';
        $data .= '</ul>';


    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo $data;
```

Comment: Please, explain a more detailed what you want to achieve. You want to add `the_title` and `more_links` but to what: to one category or to all categories?  Where you want to print category links - after each post (because different posts can be attached to different categories), or after all posts are printed. Because right now you get categories from last printed post, and print only first of them `$categories[0]`

Comment: I'd like to add the category title and more link for each category. I want to show category title, 4 latest posts with the post title and featured image and then show a more link which takes you to the category page. I'd like to do this for each category.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you ran this shortcode from this plugin for each category and pass `category_slug` to the shortcode, to be able to get the last 4 posts, because of this line from

```php
$post_args: 'category_name' => $category,
```

If so, then you already have current category slug here and you can grab category data with

```php
get_category_by_slug( $category );
```

Then you can do this

```php
<?php
    $curr_cat = get_category_by_slug( $category );

    $data .= '<div class="more-home-link">';
    $data .=    '<a href="'.get_category_link( $curr_cat->cat_ID ).'">More</a>';
    $data .= '</div>';

    $data .= '<div class="home-title">';
    $data .= '<h2><a href="'.get_category_link( $curr_cat->cat_ID ).'">'.$curr_cat->cat_name.'</a></h2>';
    $data .= '</div>';
?>
```

If you use `get_the_category()`, and just grab the first result from the array, you can't be sure that you are getting the proper category, because one post can have multiple categories, and you just pick first of them, without knowing its order.

For this reason only 2 categories are shown in your result.

Also, it is not a good practice to change plugins code, because this eliminates the possibility to update this plugin later. So maybe the better way to do this is to create your own function which `echo` or `return shortcode` with category links, and then call it after each shortcode from the plugin. Something like:

```php
[shortcode category1]
your_function('category1');

[shortcode category2]
your_function('category2');
```

Comment: Ah yes you are right! Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad I could help. :) Please see my edited answer for some proposals, and if this is the answer you needed, will be glad if you mark it as corect one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat_link
```

seems to be uninitialized

also:

```
$category[0]->cat_name
```

will only show the name of the first element ( [0] ). Are the posts in multiple categories?

Probably you need something like:

```
foreach (get_categories() as $category) {
    echo '<div>..... {$category->cat_name} ....</div>';
}
```